# jquery-ui-1.9.2 dialog not positioning correctly in IE 7

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jquery-ui-1.9.2 for show dialog and its working fine in IE 8 and but in IE 7 not positioning correctly, it loads always left top even set position. Here my code,

```
$(function() {
   $("#servicePopupDivId" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       width: 400,
   });
   $( "#serviceDivId" ).click(function() {
      $( "#servicePopupDivId" ).dialog( "open" );
   });
});
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Do you have a doctype on your page?

Comment: I used common header file for include other libs. if i put <!doctype html> it works and it breaks some css in other pages.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. jQuery UI assumes you are using a valid doctype, not using a doctype is usually a bad idea, but is very common in old legacy applications. The best way to fix it would be to redo the css, however in practice that's a bad idea due to how many pages that could potentially affect. I'd suggest just not using the dialog if possible, maybe even not jQuery UI at all because i'd expect a lot of the widgets to not work properly in IE7 qirksmode.